# css linear gradient in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

im trying to get this gradient to work in Firefox

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,transparent),color-stop(50%,transparent),color-stop(50%,$panda), color-stop(100%,$panda)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
```

I've tried with this, but no luck ?

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0, #fff 50%, $panda 100%);
```

Comment: Webkit syntax obviously won't work. Try a online converter of some kind? colorzilla below is good.

Comment: I like this CSS generator: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: The syntax is: `-webkit-linear-gradient` not `-webkit-gradient`.

Comment: You beat me shodev that was my thought.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your version of Firefox, you may have to use the prefix `-moz` when using background linear-gradients.

**Here's a general example:**

```
.box_gradient {
  background-color: #444444;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Chrome, Safari 4+ */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 10-25, iOS 5+, Safari 5.1+ */
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Firefox 3.6-15 */
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Opera 11.10-12.00 */
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
```

The Mozilla documentation would have more examples on how to render these gradients in Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Also, refer to a nice handy resource here that I generally use: http://css3please.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:

```
 background: -moz-linear-gradient($panda, transparent);

 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFF 0, #fff 50%, $panda 100%);
```